How to find out what is causing a systemd-coredump?
I keep seeing an error like this with journalctl -f:
dec 29 19:43:31 mashenka kernel: git-remote-http[30150]: segfault at 18 ip 0000576c7321949f sp 00007ffd619e7920 error 4 in git-remote-http[b049f,576c7316d000+d5000] likely on CPU 2 (core 2, socket 0)
dec 29 19:43:31 mashenka kernel: Code: 44 89 e6 4c 89 ef e8 c0 2a f9 ff c5 fa 7e 04 24 85 c0 0f 84 03 fc ff ff e9 eb fd ff ff 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 15 f9 5e 05 00 <48> 39 5a 18 0f 84 07 01 00 00 c4 e1 f9 7e c7 44 89 e6 c5 f9 d6 04
dec 29 19:43:31 mashenka systemd-coredump[30151]: Process 30150 (git-remote-http) of user 1000 terminated abnormally with signal 11/SEGV, processing...
dec 29 19:43:31 mashenka systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 30151/UID 0).
dec 29 19:43:31 mashenka systemd-coredump[30152]: [] Process 30150 (git-remote-http) of user 1000 dumped core.

                                                  Stack trace of thread 30150:
                                                  #0  0x0000576c7321949f n/a (n/a + 0x0)
                                                  ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
dec 29 19:43:31 mashenka systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@79-30151-0.service: Deactivated successfully.

Something is apparently trying to run every minute and fails. I have no idea what it could be. Is there a way I can track this down?

The errors say the process that dumped core is git-remote-http, which likely handles https connections as well as http ones.  Does this computer host git repositories or have commands that fetch/update a git repository at another site/computer?

It should not as far as I know. I recently moved to CachyOS (based on arch), I do not know if that has a repo that needs to be polled, but I guess that would not run under my user. I also have gitstatusd running under my user, but completely killing it doesn't change the 1 minute pull (plus it has no reason to continuously poll remotes). Is it possible to track down a pid after it quite where it originated from?

use coredumpctl info to get more info about the last coredump, including the full Command Line.

@meuh thanks, I'm now a bit closer:  Command Line: /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https https://github.com/moriyoshi/cyrus-sasl-xoauth2.git https://github.com/moriyoshi/cyrus-sasl-xoauth2.git Not that I know what would be wanting to poll that every minute and why it's failing though ...

Found the culprit! The OS came with a "check arch updates every minute" script.
